# open() is not creating a new file

Tags: python

I am trying to create a text file and write to it but the file is not being created as it states the file is not found.

I am using this line of code which PyCharm as my IDE:

with open(f"journal/{date}.txt","w") as file:

And I am expecting python to create the file but it is not.  The folder in which to create the file does exist.  I am receiving the error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'journal/2024-01-25.txt'

I am new to python so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The directory "journal" must exist for that line to work.

Comment: From where were you running the Python script?